# Eclipse folders with resources inside Java projects to compile / execution (bin) dir

Tags: java, eclipse

a little thing which is bothering me for awhile when writing some little java programs to try out some stuff.
I have my project dir in the Eclipse package explorer along with the /src package, along with a /lib and a /resources folder.

Now when i let eclipse run/debug my program and all my relative locations to those dirs are not found since eclipse creats a /bin directory but does not copy my folders.

Can i somehow instruct eclipse to copy my folders into the bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the folders you would like to have copied into the bin folder to the source folders.

Right click on your project and choose *Properties*.
Select *Java build Path* on the left, and click the *Source* tab.

That should look something like this:

[image: Eclipse JavaBuildPath Source]

Click *Add Folder...* to add your /lib and /resource folders.

Comment: yeah it worked somehow, but strangely when i add /lib/abc it will be copied as only /abc